# Listing most recently modified sections in Notebook?

Tags: notebooks

I'd like to get a clickable list of all "Sections" that have been recently modified in my notebook, grouped by day of modification. "Modified" Section means, some cell under that Section heading has been modified.

The following gives the list of most recently modified cells, but I'd like this to point to the "Section" object instead of the actual cell, I guess this needs some kind of traversal up the cell hierarchy, any tips?

```
notebookCellData = 
  ResourceFunction["NotebookCellData", 
   ResourceSystemBase -> 
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/api/1.0"];
Take[ReverseSortBy[
  notebookCellData[
   EvaluationNotebook[], {"CellChangeTimes"}], #CellChangeTimes &], 
 UpTo[10]]
```

Comment: replace `EvaluationNotebook[]` with `Cells[CellStyle -> "Section"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the section containing a given cell by using the {"CounterValue", "Section"} current value. Leveraging this idea produces:

```
cellButton[cell_] := Button[RawBoxes @ NotebookRead[cell], SelectionMove[cell, All, Cell]]

ModifiedSections[date_:0] := Module[{sections=Cells[CellStyle->"Section"], data, abs = AbsoluteTime[date]},
    data = Cases[
        Thread[{Max/@CurrentValue[Cells[], CellChangeTimes], Cells[], CurrentValue[Cells[], {"CounterValue","Section"}]}],
        {s_, c_, i_?Positive} /; s>abs :> {s, c, sections[[i]]}
    ];
    CreateWindow @ PaletteNotebook @ Dataset @ Reverse @ KeySort @ GroupBy[
        data, 
        DayRound @* First -> Rest, 
        GroupBy[#, cellButton @* Last -> First, Column]&
    ]
]
```