Finding cells modified on in a particular week?
I have a directory with ".nb" files (currently 503 of them), and I know that I've been modifying one of them on week 45 of 2023.
I'm looking for code that will list .nb files that have a cell modified in this week
I would then use this answer by Carl Woll to narrow down: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/293658/217

I would probably use grep. Every cell should have a CellChangeTimes option (unless you've disabled tracking of cell changes), so you can just grep on that for files in your directory. Then I'd do some processing on the result to select the change times that fit your target range. The CellChangeTimes are in absolute time, so you'll need to translate your target date range into something you can compare to absolute time.

You could even do this within Mathematica with Run. Probably easier that way anyway, cause then you have easy tools to convert DateTime objects to absolute time to prep for the comparison step. Run your grep command and save the results in a file. Process that file looking for matching times. You can probably even infer which exact cells were edited by counting the matching lines per file (each line should correspond to a cell, I think, so just sort of index each line for each file and use the index of each match to find the cell).

Does this satisfy?
(*Helper function to get the modification date of each cell*)
getCellModDates[nbFile_] := 
  Module[{nb, cells2, timestampsf}, 
   nb = NotebookOpen[nbFile, Visible -> ! False];
   cells = NotebookRead[Cells[nb]];
   timestamps = 
    Cases[cells, (CellChangeTimes -> times_) :> times, Infinity];
   (*NotebookClose[nb];*)
   Flatten[timestamps]];

(*Convert a timestamp to the corresponding week number*)
toWeekNumber[time_] := DateValue[time, "Week"];

(*Define the target year and week*)
targetYear = 2024;
targetWeek = 43;

(*Main function:Filter files modified in the target week*)
findNotebooksByWeek[dir_, year_, week_] := 
  Module[{files, matchingFiles}, files = FileNames["*.nb", dir];
   Print[files];
   matchingFiles = 
    Select[files, 
     AnyTrue[getCellModDates[#], 
       toWeekNumber[#] == week && DateValue[#, "Year"] == year &] &];
   matchingFiles];

(*Execute the function*)
modifiedFiles = 
  findNotebooksByWeek[NotebookDirectory[], targetYear, targetWeek];

You'll have to replace NotebookDirectory[] with your directory. Also the dates.

That just tried to open each one of my 503 notebooks in the front-end. I guess I need to run it through command-line interface somehow?

you can also try removing the ! from  Visible -> ! False . And Uncomment the line where the notebook is closed. Also you could try limiting how many it opens at once.
